# Use the result of one Mysql command in Another Mysql Command?

Tags: php, mysql

Excuse my ignorance but I'm having a tough time figuring this out.

I'm trying to take the result from one mysql command, and use it in another command.

Here's my code, it doesnt work.

```
//select the event end date of event ID
$sql = "SELECT enddate FROM mm_eventlist_dates WHERE id = $id";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

//plug in the event end date, find event that starts the next day
$sql = "SELECT id FROM mm_eventlist_dates WHERE startdate = date_add($result, INTERVAL 1 DAY)";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
echo "Next Event ID" . $row['id'];
```

I'm so lost.

Please help!

Thanks, Nick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand what you're trying to accomplish, it looks like you want to find all the events that start the day after a given event. Correct? In that case, what you want to do is a self-join, that is, join a table to itself. You need to give at least one occurrence of the table an alias so SQL can tell them apart.

So maybe something like this:

```
SELECT e2.id
FROM mm_eventlist_dates e1
join mm_eventlist_dates e2 on e2.startdate = date_add(e1.enddate, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
where e1.id=$id
```

Comment: Ah, I see that between the time when I brought up this screen and when I posted an answer, JamesMLV posted a virtually identical answer. Smart guy, that JamesMLV.

Comment: His query didn't work for me though. And you were more detailed. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason that you can't combine them in to one query?

```
SELECT m1.id FROM mm_eventlist_dates m1  
JOIN mm_eventlist_dates m2 ON m1.startdate = date_add(m2.enddate, INTERVAL 1 DAY)  
WHERE m2.id = $id
```

Answer (score 0):

mysql_query() returns a result set, not an actual database item.  To do what you want above, do something similar to this (doesn't include error checking etc):

```
//select the event end date of event ID
$sql = "SELECT enddate FROM mm_eventlist_dates WHERE id = $id";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

$enddateRow = mysql_fetch_array($result);

//plug in the event end date, find event that starts the next day
$sql = "SELECT id FROM mm_eventlist_dates WHERE startdate = date_add('" . $enddateRow["enddate"] . "', INTERVAL 1 DAY)";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
echo "Next Event ID" . $row['id'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use $result directly in date_add. Call mysql_fetch_array (as you do a few lines later), and use $row['enddate'].

Answer (score 0):

```
//select the event end date of event ID
$sql = "SELECT enddate FROM mm_eventlist_dates WHERE id = $id";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$enddate = $row['enddate'];

//plug in the event end date, find event that starts the next day
$sql = "SELECT id FROM mm_eventlist_dates WHERE startdate = date_add($enddate, INTERVAL 1 DAY)";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
echo "Next Event ID" . $row['id'];
```

I think

Answer (score 0):

You can not use the result of mysql_query directly in another query, you need to fetch the value first.

Instead of

```
$result = mysql_query($sql);

//plug in the event end date, find event that starts the next day
$sql = "SELECT id FROM mm_eventlist_dates WHERE startdate = date_add($result, INTERVAL 1 DAY)";
```

Try

```
   $result = mysql_query($sql);
   $enddate = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

    //plug in the event end date, find event that starts the next day
    $sql = "SELECT id FROM mm_eventlist_dates WHERE startdate = date_add($enddate, INTERVAL 1 DAY)";
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
//select the event end date of event ID
$sql = "SELECT enddate FROM mm_eventlist_dates WHERE id = $id";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)
//plug in the event end date, find event that starts the next day
$sql = "SELECT id FROM mm_eventlist_dates WHERE startdate = date_add(".$row['enddate'].", INTERVAL 1 DAY)";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
echo "Next Event ID" . $row['id'];
```